# C# - Recursively access subsection of List<>

Tags: c#, list, recursion

I'm working on a program that operates as a Car Park simulator. To do this, I have:

A class called `ParkingSpace`

A `List<ParkingSpace>`

A class called `Level` (contains `List<ParkingSpace>` as an attribute)

A `List<Level>`

The number of spaces in the `List<ParkingSpace>` list is decided via user input. Once all of the `ParkingSpace` instances have been added to the list, I would like to spread them evenly across the number of levels (i.e. if there are 30 spaces and 3 levels, 10 spaces are added to the `List<ParkingSpace>` attribute of each `Level` instance.

With this example in mind, I have tried to get the first 10 spaces into the first level, the middle 10 spaces into the second level, and the last 10 spaces into the third level.
I have tried to carry this out using a `for` loop, and the `List<ParkingSpace>.getRange()` method, as shown below:

```
//number of spaces to be set on each level
//total spaces divided by levels to be spread across
int spacesPerLevel = spaces.Count / numLevels;

//for as many levels as there are
for (int i = 0; i < numLevels; i++)
{
    //level at index holds range
    //level index multiplied by number of spaces on any one level
    int listRangeStart = (i * spacesPerLevel);

    //create sub-collection of spaces to be applied to level
    ParkingSpaces subSpaces = spaces.getRange(listRangeStart, spacesPerLevel);

    //add these spaces to level
    Level level = new Level(subSpaces);
    //add created level to collection of levels
    Add(level);

    //remove these spaces from ParkingSpaces collection once applied to level
    //try to prevent loose collection of spaces not applied to levels
    spaces.RemoveRange(listRangeStart, spacesPerLevel);
}
```

I'd have thought this would have worked fine, but for some reason I continue to get an `OutOfRangeException` on the `getRange()` method.

I've done the maths on the algorithm and it should work as far as I know. Can anyone spot any problems here that might be throwing it off?
Alternatively, is there a simpler way to go about adding a subset of the main list another list recursively?

Comment: Did you try debugging? Where exactly that exception happens? What are the values when it happens?

Comment: Hi there, since posting I have managed to find a way around the exception. However, I have just attempted to output the IDs of the spaces on each level to confirm that the code has worked, but the subset of the list does not seem to have been applied to the `Level` class' attribute. Not at all sure how this would happen. @MarcinJuraszek

Comment: What is the Add method here? is this the Add of the List? Also, what if there are 22 spaces and 3 levels? That would mean uneven distribution of spaces per level.

Comment: This is the add method that comes with the list, yes. And the numbers of spaces of levels are input by the user in a 'Number of Levels/Number of Spaces Per Level' format, so the number of spaces will always work out to be the same on each level @Jure

Comment: Try removing a last line .RemoveRange. It should work.

Comment: Just removed the RemoveRange command, tried to get the program to output the name of each level and then the spaces it contains but then it only outputs the name of the levels. I take this as the passed in list not being assigned to the attribute? @Jure

Comment: Could you show the code that outputs level names and space names or ids?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because of the `RemoveRange` call, thus decreasing the size of the list, thus the error. To fix this simply change the line with `.GetRange` to this:

```
ParkingSpaces subSpaces = spaces.GetRange(0, spacesPerLevel);
```

And the line where you call `RemoveRange` to this:

```
spaces.RemoveRange(0, spacesPerLevel);
```

Comment: 20+10 does equal to 30, but if you try taking 10 elements starting from 20th element, you'll end up at 29th :)

Comment: @Marcin: You could also try just removing a call to .RemoveRange and it should work, since you're incrementing startIndex on getRange.

Comment: @Pireax You should include updating the last line as well, or go with @Jure's suggestion. `spaces.RemoveRange(0, spacesPerLevel);`

Comment: @tehDorf True, anwsered too quickly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> Alternatively, is there a simpler way to go about adding a subset of the main list another list recursively?

Well there isn't really any recursion involved in your code anyway, but here is a simple way to so it:

```
for(int i=0;i<numLevels;i++)
{
        var skip =i*spacesPerLevel;     
        var subSpaces = spaces.Skip(start).Take(spacesPerLevel);
        var level = new Level(subSpaces);
        Add(level);
}
```

Effectively what you're creating is a paging algorithm, and since you're using `List<T>`, which implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you can take advantage of the [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx) methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the spaces from the collection, so you can't get the range you want because that range does not exist anymore, i suggest to use a queue instead of a list, dequeue the elements while you reach the maximum amount per level.

Will be a good exercise too.

```
foreach (var level in levels) {
    while(spaces.any() && level.spaces.count() <= maxPerLevel) {
        level.spaces.add (spaces.dequeue());
    }
}
```

You should also think to not evenly divisibile numbers, what if someone input 3 levels and 11 spaces?

Comment: Hi there, I am not particularly familiar with Queues and their functionality. Would you mind terribly to include a simulation of my above code using a queue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try LINQ approach:

```
var count = 0;
var spacesPerLevel = spaces.Count / numLevels;
var levels = spaces
               .GroupBy(t => count++ / spacesPerLevel)
               .Select(t => new Level(new ParkingSpaces(t.ToList())))
               .ToList();
AddRange(levels);
```

Of course, there are few things to be aware of. Your `Level` constructor must take `ParkingSpaces` as an argument and your `ParkingSpaces` class constructor must take en `IEnumerable<ParkingSpace>` as an argument.
LINQ expression will return `List<Level>`, which you can use in `AddRange` method for adding all levels at once.